# Hadoop in Clojure - Where to begin?

Tags: hadoop, clojure, bigdata, apache-storm

I use Clojure at work and recently started reading Hadoop - The Definitive Guide. I was wondering if there was a good library to start writing Hadoop jobs in Clojure.

And how different is Storm from Hadoop and where can i learn more about it? Links would really help.

Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 4):

First, Clojure provides every thing you need to use Java code in your application. But if you need a natural Clojure taste when coding in Hadoop, then have a look at: [Cascalog](https://github.com/nathanmarz/cascalog). It is created by Storm creator, Nathan Marz.

How Storm differs from Hadoop? Read Storm documentations.

Comment: Thank you! You're talking about java interop in Clojure right? Cascalog looks interesting. would take a look.

Comment: Yes of course, I mean Java interop. What else? :)